# Bookshelf.js - How to get a column from join table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have a User model and a Course model, and they have a many-to-many relationship, so basically users can join multiple courses and courses have many users (students). I have a join table and I'm trying to add additional information to the join table. Basically, users have a monthly quota of questions they can ask per course. So i've added a quota column to the User_Course join table. I'm having trouble accessing the quota column. Below is the relevant code to give an idea.

```
var User = DB.Model.extend({
    Courses: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany('Course', 'User_Course', 'userId', 'courseId');
    },
});

var Course = DB.Model.extend({
    Users: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany('User', 'User_Course', 'courseId', 'userId');
    }
})
```

And User_Course is my join table that has the additional quota column:

```
**User_Course:**
userId: int
courseId: int
quota: int
```

I want to be able to decrement my quota value. I'm able to update it using updatePivot, but I'm unable to simply get the value thats in quota. Here is the code I'm using to update the value:

```
var userPromise = new User.User({userId: userId}).fetch({withRelated: ['Courses']});
userPromise.then(function(_user) {
    _user.related('enrolledCourses').updatePivot({courseId:courseId, quota:1}).then(function() {
        return;
    })

})
```

As you can see, I'm updating the quota value to 1 every time here. I'd like to programmatically determine what the current quota value is, and then decrement it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `withPivot`. For example, `return this.belongsToMany(Comment).withPivot(['created_at', 'order']);` you can place here your quota and you'll get it when loading the relation.

**Update:**

OK, here's an example:

```
    new Town().where({
            town_number: 2301
        }).fetchAll({
            columns: ['town_title', 'id'],
            withRelated: [{
                'address': function(qb) {
                    qb.select('addresses.town_id', 'addresses.participant_id');
                    qb.columns('addresses.street_name');
                    // here you could simply do qb.where({something_id: 1}); as well
                }
            }]
        }).then(function(result) {
            res.json(result);
        });
```

So basically instead of just saying `withRelated: ['table_name']`, you define that table name as an object, with the property `table_name` and `function` as a value, that has a query builder (`qb`) and you can query that table separately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! So I believe in my case the statement you've shown would look like this: `return this.belongsToMany('Course', 'User_Course', 'userId', 'courseId').withPivot(['quota'])`, but I believe this is attempting to give me all the **courses** related to the user, when I want returned just the number in the quota column at given courseId and userId.

Comment: You can limit that too when querying. Just pass the query attribute in withRelated statement

Comment: would you be able to edit your answer with a more complete example? I'm playing around with the withRelated statement but I'm not sure I'm using it properly. I think withRelated takes a model ie 'comments' and gives back the related object. When I want to pass in parameters ie 'courseId=1' & 'userId=2' in order to get back the value in the quota column. Sorry, i'm still trying to understand bookshelf, i'm pretty new to it.

Comment: OK, I've edited my response. Hopefully, this clears some of the confusion!

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this a little later today, but its already taught me something new. I didn't know withRelated could take inputs that way. Its not necessary, but I'd also appreciate it if you could explain to me the benefits of using bookshelfs functions vs. the drawbacks of using raw sql queries in knex. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I'm not really familiar with what's going on under the hood of Bookshelf (and Knex, upon which Bookshelf is build on), but I think performance-wise there is no substantial differences if you mix knex within bookshelf models. I suppose that using just Knex could fasten your program, since you have a bit more control of which tables are joining (and how). I personally like to do as much as possible with Bookshelf and use Knex only for very specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Until I learn a more appropriate way to do this, I'm using knex.raw to use a mysql statement to decrement the quota column. In my controller I call decrementQuota and pass in the userId and courseId:

```
function decrementQuota(userId, courseId) {
    new User.User({userId: userId}).decrementQuota(userId, courseId);
}
```

In my user model is where the knex.raw call updates the User_Course by decrementing the value of quota.

```
var User = DB.Model.extend({
    decrementQuota: function(uid, cid) {
        DB.knex.raw('update User_Course set quota = quota -1 where userId=' + uid + ' and courseId=' + cid).then(function(quota) {

        });
    },
})
```